# CSS id / class, style change not applying

Tags: html, css

I'm kinda new to HTML, PHP and CSS and I have an issue with my stylesheet not applying some changes.

Here is the part in my HTML where I've got an issue:

```
<div class="container" id="contact">
    Some Random Text
    <br/><br/>
    More Random Text
</div>
```

And the corresponding ID in my stylesheet:

```
#contact{
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

I am using Bootstrap for the grid and such thing and I've already made sure to call the Bootstrap stylesheet before my own (to not overwrite my own changes).

What I really don't understand is that if I type the following HTML, I got the result I need but not with the previous one:

```
<div class="container" style="color:white; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;">
    Some Random Text
    <br/><br/>
    More Random Text
</div>
```

I hope that my question is clear, and that I haven't made to many English mistakes (not a native speaker).

Comment: Have you included the css file on the page?

Comment: I'm pretty sure i did, i got the following to call my stylesheet:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="all" type="text/css">

And the stylesheet is in the css folder inside my project.

Comment: check the console, see the source files maybe the `CSS` file is being cached.

Comment: Check my answer and try it

Comment: Thx @ths for the suggestion, I've looked into it and find a working solution. 
I've posted an answer to my question for other users.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you didn't link your css right? 
For example, if you have your index.html file and style.css file in one directory, you may write like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

But if your css file on the folder "css" don't forget to write: `href="css/style.css"`

Answer (score 1):

After following Ths's answer, I've looked for a solution to this possible caching problem.
And after changing my stylesheet call from:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css"href="css/style.css" >
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="all" type="text/css <?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>">
```

It seems to now update properly.
Here is a link to the explanation on this CSS-caching problem:
https://css-tricks.com/can-we-prevent-css-caching/

Comment: the `Console` is your friend, it knows things you'd probably didn't know. Try to stick to it. And by the way, don't rely on the time trick on production, you sure need to cache some files when your site is live, a better approach is you append the hash of the file in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

It’s because your rules are on the html tag what has more precedence

You should identify with your developer tools what styles are effectively setting the styles

Style precedence is a bit complex to solve as « you new » but first as your rule is « active » (seem not but but using developer tools to see it will help)

Could also try to be more precise with a « .container#contact » does it work ?

Order of stylesheet processing do not drive precedence logic but in some cases it change the result is « active » styles

F12 and Check styles tab...